# Regular check Chinese punctuation, return true in development mode, return false in release

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

Why the verification does not pass when the user gives Chinese punctuation in the app? [issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24847)

Regular check Chinese punctuation, return true in development mode, return false in release

React Native version:

```
System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.4
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6267U CPU @ 2.90GHz
      Memory: 38.94 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 11.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
        Build Tools: 23.0.1, 23.0.3, 25.0.0, 25.0.2, 25.0.3, 26.0.1, 27.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
        System Images: android-19 | Intel x86 Atom, android-21 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.5429.30.34.5452501
      Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
      react-native: 0.58.5 => 0.58.5 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-config: 0.11.7
```

### Steps To Reproduce

1.For example, the following check returns true under normal conditions, true in react native debug mode, false after release

```
const regExpTextInput = /[^\x00-\xff]/;
alert(regExpTextInput.test("。"))
```

Describe what you expected to happen:
Release support for Chinese symbols

Snack, code example, or link to a repository:

```
const regExpTextInput = /[^\x00-\xff]/;
alert(regExpTextInput.test("。"))
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how to solve this problem? The user now enters Chinese punctuation in the app and the verification is not passed.

Comment: Are you using "remote JS debugging"?

Comment: This problem occurs if you do not use "remote JS debugging", but Achrive, or change Edit Scheme>Build Configuration -> Release.

Comment: I mean in development mode. Do you use that?

Comment: In development mode, both remote and simulator are normal.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I created the latest version of react native 59, no such problem, I think I should upgrade.